# Is it possible to pass a bash array as a variable to awk?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, awk

I have a large number data that I am importing from text files. The files are preformatted so that I can import each column as a bash array:

> 2GYS  chain=(A B) hresname=(BMA FUC NAG NDG)  hresnumber=( )  hatom=( )

Now I would like to extract information from files containing several lines formatted like this:

> ATOM      1  N   THR A   4      30.127  13.123   1.297  1.00 39.96           N

For instance, I would like to extract all lines in which the first column is ATOM and the fifth column matches the chain array (in this case, it would be both A and B).

UPDATE. This is what I have tried:

```
for c in "${chain[@]}" ; do
  awk -v pdbid="$pdbid" -v c="$c" '{ if($1 == "ATOM" && $5==c) { print $0 } }' ${pdbid}.pdb >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb
done

for c in "${chain[@]}" ; do
 for r in "${hresname[@]}" ; do
   awk -v pdbid="$pdbid" -v c="$c" -v r="$r" '{ if($1 == "HETATM" && $5==c && $4==r) { print $0 } }' ${pdbid}.pdb >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb
 done
done
```

The problem is that, as expected this produces files with either chain A or B but not the file with both. In addition it does not produce all possible combinations of the arrays "chain" and "hresname", it just adds "hresname" to the files for which only one "chain" was available.

Comment: do you mean `$5==c` in your awk code? `$5=c` assigns the value in var 'c' to the 5th column in the current record. More generally, why not just build some code in awk to parse your input file AND if possible, change the format of your input file to make it require less parsing when it is in awk. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that mistake, Shawn Chin. Changing the format of the input is not a big issue. As for your first suggestion, it is a bit more complicated due to 2 reasons: 1) This script belongs to a long bash pipeline; and 2) I do not know any awk at all.

Comment: Given the above input data, can you post the desired final output, and psuedo-code of your pipeline. Do you really mean for each 'record' to be on one line (per your example data)? The awk that you show is perfectly idomatic, but you may benefit from using associative arrays, and printf statements.

Comment: I too don't understand what you want. What does it mean when you say the 5th column should match both A and B? Is it the value "AB" or "BA"? You do need to show a larger sample input.

Comment: I am still trying to decipher what you want to achieve, i.e. what your input, output look like. However I notice the AWK expression '{ if($1 == "ATOM" && $5==c) { print $0 } }' can be shorten to '$1 == "ATOM" && $5==c' which will do the same thing, but more compact.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to build part of your awk script in bash, specifically the matching function.

You seem to want fields that match `$1 == "ATOM" && ($5==c[0] || $5==c[1]...) {print $0}` exported to the file.

In bash, construct the matching function as:

```
cmatch="\$5==\"${chain[0]}\""
for element in $(seq 1 $((${#chain[@]} - 1))); do cmatch+=" || \$5==\"${chain[$element]}\""; done
#cmatch should now be of the form "$5==A || $5==B"

#do the same thing for rmatch
rmatch="\$4==\"${hresname[0]}\""
for element in $(seq 1 $((${#hresname[@]} - 1))); do rmatch+=" || \$4==\"${hresname[$element]}\""; done
```

Now your awk-scripts can be adjusted to include the needed bits: (Quotes continue to be a pain, since you need to make sure $1 gets down to awk unmolested, but $cmatch is evaluated.)

```
rmatch='$1=="HETATM" && ('"$cmatch"') && ('"$rmatch"')'  #order is important here :)
cmatch='$1=="ATOM" && ('"$cmatch"')'
```

So now your matching script should be complete.

```
awk "$cmatch" ${pdbid}.pdb >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_c.pdb
awk "$rmatch" ${pdbid}.pdb >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_c.pdb
```

I don't really understand the output file name, `../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb`, since that would seem to indicate seperate files for each element of c, which is what you don't want?

If you want these divided by elements of c, then it's slightly simpler, construct the rmatch array like above, and then do something like

```
for c in "${chain[@]}" ; do
  awk -v c="$c" '$1=="ATOM" && $5==c' ${pdbid}.pdb  >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb
  awk -v c="$c" '$1=="HETATM" && $5==c && ('"$rmatch"')' ${pdbid}.pdb  >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb
done
```

If you want all ATOM elements first, or...

```
for c in "${chain[@]}" ; do
  awk -v c="$c" '$5==c && ($1=="ATOM" || ($1=="HETATM" && ('"$rmatch"')))' ${pdbid}.pdb  >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${c}.pdb
done
```

if you want them intermixed